# Can I use Pardot api to get prospect list by email domain name?

Tags: email, pardot

My task is sending customized emails to different prospects by their email domain. Assuming we have 5000 different domains, how to use Pardot api to get prospect lists according to their email domains and send them separately? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably. Here is how I would approach it:

1) Query all prospects (/api/prospect/version/4/do/query)
2) Split their email address on the @ symbol
3) For each domain create a list (/api/list/version/4/do/create) and add prospects matching that domain to that list (/api/listMembership/version /4/do/create/list_id//prospect_id/)

For more on how to use these API endpoints check out the [official documentatio](http://developer.pardot.com/)n.